# How can I circumvent bot protection when scraping full NYTimes articles?

Tags: web, go, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape full book reviews from the New York Times in order to perform sentiment analysis on them. I am aware of the [NY Times API](https://developer.nytimes.com/books_api.json#/Console/GET/reviews.%7Bformat%7D) and am using it to get book review URLs, but I need to devise a scraper to get the full article text, as the API only gives a snippet. I believe that nytimes.com has bot protection to prevent bots from scraping the website but I know there are ways to circumvent it.

I found this [python scraper](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) that works and can pull full text from nytimes.com, but I would prefer to implement my solution in Go. Should I just port this to Go or is this solution unnecessarily complex? I have already played around with changing the User-Agent header but everything that I do in Go ends in an infinite redirect loop error.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    //"fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    //"net/url"
)

func main() {

    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())

    userAgents := [5]string{
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0",
    }

    url := "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/25/books/review/the-tsar-of-love-and-techno-by-anthony-marra.html"

    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", userAgents[rand.Intn(len(userAgents))])

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println(string(body))
}
```

Results in:

```
2016/12/05 21:57:53 Get http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/25/books/review/the-tsar-of-love-and-techno-by-anthony-marra.html?_r=4: stopped after 10 redirects
exit status 1
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It seems unlikely that a bot protection script would send back a redirect instead of just an error.  What page are they trying to redirect you to?

Comment: Would be great to see your code. Otherwise - Agree with David. Unlikely their response is to blame (and I believe this is confirmed by a successfully working Python script).

Comment: Try setting proper request headers, start with `User-Agent`, `Cookie` etc. You can get their values from browser's developer console.

Comment: One more hint after looking at Python code: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/blob/master/cfscrape/__init__.py
It uses a pool of user agents accessing it by random to prevent throttling you. Just implement a similar approach, even with same user agents. Maybe this is not the _only_ pre-requisite, but definitely one of the key ones.

Comment: Hi @mpmlj, thanks for your recommendation. I added the random user-agent (and updated the question's code), but I still am getting that redirect loop. I'll try playing around with more headers and keep you guys posted.

Comment: After snooping around the Network chrome tab, NYTimes does indeed use CloudFlare, so I think I will port cloudflare-scrape to Go.

Comment: @David it looks like they're redirecting me to `http://www.nytimes.com/glogin?URI=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2015%2F10%2F25%2Fbooks%2Freview%2Fthe-tsar-of-love-and-techno-by-anthony-marra.html%3F_r%3D0`

Comment: you probably need to add the cookies that were returned from `/glogin` page in the subsequent redirect to the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add cookies to your client:

```
var cookieJar, _ = cookiejar.New(nil)
var client = &http.Client{Jar: cookieJar}

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
// now response contains all you need and 
// you can show it on the console or save to file
```

Comment: Wow, what a simple answer! Thank you so much, I will upvote when I get enough reputation.